# How after tkinter.messagebox then entry

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox, tkinter-entry

```
ready = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("Guess", "Are you ready?")

def func():
    entry = Entry(windows,bg = "lightblue")
    entry.pack()

if ready == False:
    windows.quit()
else:
    func()
```

I just start learn tkinter and try to practice it. When i do the messagebox, i could'n entry anything in the box. How could I fix it, thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to add an entry then I suggest you use `Toplevel` and create your own message box. `Messagebox` widget is only to show a message you can't have entries in it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try Toplevel.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't use `tkinter.messagebox` directly. But if you import this, you will face no issue. I have just made a little modification to your code and now it's working fine.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox as message

windows = tkinter.Tk()
ready = message.askyesno("ready?")
#print(ready)
def func():
    e = tkinter.Entry(windows, bg="lightblue")
    e.pack()

if ready == False:
    windows.quit()
else:
    func()
windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, i import tkinter.messagebox and others same as you post, I run your code find I still could'n enter anything, but thank you for your time.